# Automation of electric machines

Tags: electrical, home-automation

I have, of course, a lot of electric machines: Computer, printer, humidifier, etc.

But I want to make them "smart" by automatizing when the humidifier will turn on everyday.

The original humidifier doesn't have this.

But is there something like "automatizable button" that will work like a "connector" between the original humidifier (or any electric machine) and the electric outlet? So that I can automatize the "automatizable button" to be "on" at, say 8 pm everyday?

Comment: A simple plug-in timer will achieve this. Are you looking for some different type of control or more sophistication?

Comment: This is really a question for the electronics or computer section of the site, but you want a home automation setup, like Z-wave, Insteon, etc. They have plug in modules that can be programmed and controlled by a computer, tablet, phone, or set on timers to come and and off whenever you like. When using the plug-in receptacle modules this type of setup can typically be used with no additional wiring whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have a couple different options in today's market. The cheapest would be a plug in timer that has to be manually set. As long as your schedule stays consistent, then this is a good option as it's well rounded and very useful. They make both ones with the push dials (as shown below) and ones with electronic displays, both are still relatively cheap.

[image: Manual timer outlet]

The next option, and between 4-5 times the price of the manual timer, is a 'smart' outlet. These work over your wifi and can be connected to a phone, tablet, or other smart device to be programmed and controlled. The cheaper version of this allows you to turn the device on or off from wherever you are (with internet service) and set up a timed schedule for when it should come on/go off. The more expensive version (about $10 more) is a little smaller and has all of the same features as the last, but also allows you to track the energy usage of whatever is plugged in. Very neat product and if you go this route, then if you're ever home at some time that the item is scheduled to be off, then you can simply pull out your phone/device to flip it on.

[image: Smart timer outlet]

Either way they'll both definitely provide some convenience to your routine.

Comment: The OP might also be interested in [120v humidisat controls](http://www.amazon.com/Honeywell-H46E1013-Humidistat-Includes-Window/dp/B000LDKD7G). They will supply power to a power cord at your desired humidity setting. Similar, temperature-controlled devices are also available.